# Name of the substance on which water cannot stay?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water

There is a show on discovery, 'You have been warned.'. In that show, once I remember seeing an unusual substance, when, on water was poured in it, even on a perfectly straight (non-slanting) table, water just didn't stay on it. It "rushed" in random directions and then when it was not in contact of the substance, it stopped. I don't remember the episode, nor the substance.

What could this substance be, or if they're a class of compounds, what are their properties? 
**Can anybody also  point out that episode?**

Comment: What you are talking about is ultrahydrophobic coatings. They can be made of different materials; personally, I am familiar with ZnO/PS nano-composites. I urge you to read more into it. Specifically, do look up the Lotus effect. I am sure you will be able to find all sorts of examples.

Comment: Have you seen that eqisode?

Comment: You may also want to consider researching lipophilicity. Although lipophilicity is not really synonymous with hydrophobicity because there are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you @getafix! Found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPM8OR6W6WE.

Comment: Can I move it to television stack exchange?